# How to prevent page refreshing? AJAX, Spring MVC

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have got a `<form>` and AJAX script that sending data from form to controller.

```
    <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="message"
                        accept-charset="utf-8" ng-app="vandh" ng-controller="validateCtrl"
                        name="messageForm" novalidation="true">

<form:textarea path="text" class="form-control" rows="1" name="message"
                            id="message" ng-model="message" required="true"></form:textarea>
                        <div style="color: black"
                            ng-show="messageForm.message.$dirty && messageForm.message.$invalid">
                            <span ng-show="messageForm.message.$error.required"><spring:message
                                code="label.entermessage" /></span>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="text-center">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" id="addMessage" name="addMessage"><spring:message
                                code="label.sendmessage"/></button>
                        </div>

</form:form>


<script>
$("#addMessage").click(function() { 
    var text = $('#message').val();
    $.ajax({ 
    type : "POST", 
    url: "/app/user/messages/${iddialog}" , 
    async : true, 
    dataType:'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data : { 
    text : text 
    } 
    }); 

    });
</script>
```

And here is my controller for this page

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/user/messages/{iddialog}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Message messages(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            @PathVariable(value = "iddialog") int iddialog, Principal principal,@RequestParam(value="text")String text ) {

        System.out.println("ITS HERE");
        if (checkingMessage(text) != true) {
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            // get current date time with Date()
            Date date = new Date();
            System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
            dialog.setIddialog(iddialog);
            Message mess = new Message();
            mess.setText(text);
            mess.setDialog(dialog);
            mess.setDate(dateFormat.format(date));
            mess.setMessender(principal.getName());
            this.messageService.addMessage(mess);
            this.dialogService.updateUnreadMessInfo(iddialog, principal.getName());

            System.out.println("message sent!");
            return mess;
            // return "redirect:/user/messages/"+iddialog;
        }
        else{
            Message mess1 = new Message();
    return mess1;
        }
}
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/messages/{iddialog}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String messagesList(@PathVariable(value = "iddialog") int iddialog, Model model, Principal principal) {
        model.addAttribute("message", new Message());
        model.addAttribute("listMessagesForUser", messageService.listMessagesForUser(iddialog));
        model.addAttribute("userDialogWith", dialogService.usernameDialogWith(iddialog, principal.getName()));
        model.addAttribute("countOfNewUsers", this.usersService.countOfNewUsers());
        model.addAttribute("allUserMess", this.dialogService.allNewMessForUser(principal.getName()));
        System.out.println("ID dialog is: " + iddialog);
        return "messagesWithUser";
    }
```

When i'm sending data from AJAX script to my controller, it returns me my Message object:
[image: Here what is my POST method returns]

But i need to prevent reloading my page when i'll submit my `<form>`. I saw a lot of guides but it's the highest result that i get! Help me pls! What i need to do that my page will not refresh when i'm submiting my form!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to `return false` from your click handler to prevent the default action (submitting the form) from executing.

Comment: that for your answer! Could you show me an example at my code pls!?

Comment: it gives me an error 

`Failed to load resource: http://localhost:8080/app/user/messages/7 the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)`

Comment: @SergShapoval: You need to debug your server to figure out why it's saying no.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop default action using prevent default.
https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Answer (score 0):

Based from your front end code you are using AngularJS, but you are using jQuery to trigger the button click.

What you can do is create a function in your controller(validateCtrl) to handle the click event and post the message model to the backend, by using the ng-click directive of angular and add an attribute `type='button'` to button to prevent triggering the submit of the form.

Your button would be like:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="addMessage" name="addMessage" ng-click="addMessageClick(message)">
```

Documentation on Angular $http: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app', []).controller('validateCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope) {

    //You could pass the message model here as a parameter or access it using $scope.message
    $scope.addMessageClick = function(message) {
      //Use AngularJS's $http or jQuery Ajax to post to backend and send the message model
      console.log('test');
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head></head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <form name="messageForm" ng-controller="validateCtrl" novalidate>
    <button ng-click="addMessageClick('test')">Test</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added the submit button with in the form, and when you click on the submit button along with ajax call because of the form the page is getting reloaded

Please put that submit button outside of the form tag and check, your page reloading problem will be resolved